# App Tile Properties in Windows Start Menu

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps, windows-10, regedit, startmenu

I'm wondering if there is a way to access the background colours, among other properties (allowable resizes, etc), of the apps tiles that are found in the start menu of Windows 10.

If such a method exists, it should apply the same in Windows 8/8.1.

Is this information stored somewhere in windows or in the apps themselves?

Answer (score 2):

The [secondary tiles](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/SecondaryTiles) sample on the GitHub samples [Microsoft provided for Win 10](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples) may be useful.

**This sample demonstrates the following scenarios:**

- Pinning a secondary tile to the Start screen Removing a secondary
  tile from the Start screen
- Enumerating all secondary tiles owned by
  the calling app
- Determining whether a particular tile is currently
  pinned to the Start screen
- Processing arguments when the app is
  activated through a secondary tile
- Sending a local tile notification
  and badge notification to the secondary tile
- Using the app bar to pin
  and unpin tiles. (JavaScript and C# only)
- Updating the secondary
  tile's default logo
- Selecting from among alternative secondary tile
  visuals (Windows only)
- Selecting from among alternative secondary
  tile visuals as an asynchronous operation (Windows only)

Note Some functionality in the sample requires that the tile can receive notifications. Tile notifications can be disabled by a user for a single app or for all apps, or by a system administrator by using group policy.